# Can I upgrade PowerShell versions from within PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, upgrade

I have a Windows 7 SP1 box, running PowerShell version 2 (which shipped with it). Now I need to upgrade to either version 3.0 or 4.0, in order to take advantage of some of the newer cmdlets.

In search of answers, I came across this great tutorial: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/06/02/weekend-scripter-install-powershell-3-0-on-windows-7.aspx.

This tutorial was fine, but I was surprised to not see any mention of a command line/cmdlet option for running such an upgrade (something comparable to `Update-Help` cmdlet, for instance) - especially given that the philosophy of PowerShell is automation!

Is there a cmdlet/script that I can deploy to upgrade my PowerShell installations across different computers?

Comment: since powershell must be closed to install wmf the answer is probably "no". You could just do a silent install via a batch file. I guess you could call that batch in powershell but you would have to make shure that all your powershell instances are closed during the installation. One could probably start the installer from powershell as well but would have to choose a method that starts the process so that it doesnt get closed if the ps session ends

Comment: Thanks @Paul. That makes sense, and I'm already trying that already. But then it is already telling me `The update is not applicable to your computer`. Now I have SP1, and thought that should be ok. This all goes to show why it all should have been more "automatic".

Comment: do you have the needed .net framework installed? if yes then you might have run into this bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/771892/v3-installation-says-the-update-is-not-applicable-to-your-computer-on-some-versions-of-windows-7 see the sites workaround tab for a solution to this

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this.

As a quick answer, run this:

```
iex "& { $(irm https://aka.ms/install-powershell.ps1) } -UseMSI"
```

For a full explanation, see [a related thread on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1287032/update-powershell-through-command-line).